How can I extract data from a GeoTIFF at specific x, y co-ordinates in C++
I am an R user but a novice in C++. I need a C++ workflow that returns the value of a GeoTiff at a specific (x, y) coordinate. The GeoTiff contains 1 layer. The layer is a 2-dimensional array. Each cell contains a floating point number (FLT4S) that (in my case) defines the depth of the seabed in a specific location. The coordinate reference system is Universal Transverse Mercator with units in metres.
In R, it is easy to read a GeoTiff and extract the value of the GeoTiff in a specific location using the terra package:
library(terra)

# Load GeoTiff
# * This is a map of the seabed depth off the west coast of Scotland
f <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edwardlavender/patter/main/inst/extdata/dat_gebco.tif"
(r <- terra::rast(f))

#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 264, 190, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
#> extent      : 695492.1, 714492.1, 6246657, 6273057  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 29N (EPSG:32629) 
#> source      : dat_gebco.tif 
#> name        :   map_value 
#> min value   :   0.1994156 
#> max value   : 201.8856354 

# Extract value (depth) at (x, y)
# (Coordinates are in metres, matching GeoTiff)
terra::extract(r, cbind(707087.7, 6266045))
#>  map_value
#> 1   191.285

How can I do this in C++? I know terra uses C++ under the hood. terra::extract() ultimately calls a SpatRaster::extract*() C++ function*, but I can't work out what the minimal workflow for achieving the above is. Note that in my case both the coordinate pair and the GeoTiff (UTM projection) have units of metres, which may simplify the required code.
*See https://github.com/rspatial/terra/blob/master/src/extract.cpp


I highly recommend searching the internet before posting.  I've seen a lot of questions on StackOverflow about getting values from the screen.

What is the format of your raster?  Is it a BMP?  Image?  PNG?  8-bit values?  32-bit values?  How many channels?  Big Endian or Little Endian?

@ThomasMatthews this has nothing to do with getting values from the screen. The OP is referring to a spatial raster as used extensively for spatial statistics in R. It is stored in a TIF file, as you can see from the link in the code.

@AllanCameron my understanding of raster is from graphics and raster graphics.  So a raster is a row of pixels.

@ThomasMatthews in this specific setting a "raster" is a 2 dimensional array in which each cell contains a value representing some variable of interest. The file also contains enough information to reconstruct the geographical location of each cell. Furthermore, several of these arrays can be overlaid in a single file. I think the question would certainly be clearer if it were posed as "How can I extract data from a GeoTIFF at specific x, y co-ordinates in C++", but some of the confusion here stems from the fact you haven't seen this use of "raster" before, which isn't the OP's fault.

Thanks for the comments @ThomasMatthews and @AllanCameron! I have clarified the question as suggested. I think GeoTiff can support Big Endian or Little Endian & generally defaults to the latter, but I'm not sure. I have not seen any examples of how to do this elsewhere - please share if you've seen some. I think the answer is buried in the terra/spat library linked above, but I'm not sure.

Whenever I don't know how a file format works I would look up its official specification (and I don't know GeoTIFF), but it seems to be well documented : https://www.earthdata.nasa.gov/s3fs-public/imported/19-008r4.pdf

The main hurdle is to read the GeoTiff and be able to extract a particular cell (row/col). terra uses the GDAL library to read GeoTiff so have a look at that. Their docs have C++ examples. The math to compute the cell (or row/col) from the coordinates is basic, with some additional rules for coordinates on boundaries. Have a look at terra::cellFromXY or terra::rowFromY and terra::colFromX.
Here is a lot of help that shows how to do this with the TIFF package.
Your question is very broad and shows no effort. ChatGPT c.s. is probably a better place to ask for a minimal workflow for this. Here we can answer specific questions about your code, we generally do not write your code for you.

Note that manually parsing a geotiff certainly qualifies as "a bit of work" but it's hardly difficult. No need to pull ChatGPT into this: as long as you have a tiff parser available (and there are quite a few for C++) you're pretty much good to go, finding the values necessary to resolve coordinate-to-pixel and vice versa is pretty straight forward.
